# Need I destroy same POSIX mutex in all processes or just once?

Tags: process, fork, mutex, destroy

When I call pthread_mutex_destroy in a forked child process, will it make that mutex useless for the parent and other forked childs. In other words. Should I call this function only once (when noone wants to use it any more, like application exit) or I need to call it for every exitining forked processes, or both is valid?

Answer (score 0):

If you used the PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED flag, then yes, you should only destroy it in one process.  It seems that the current process that is in the critical section has the mutex and the mutex must not be destroyed when a process is in a critical section.

Comment: Hmmmm, but I just tested it and it gave me EBUSY when trying to destroy one which is currently locked and has been destroyed in unrelated process without reinitializing it in other processes. So for forked processes it seems to be correct (Note I am not using threads, so the mutexes are actually copied by fork.)

Comment: Ah, I forgot that you mentioned the fork.  A Process contains threads, and threads cannot control anything outside of the process.  A pthread_mutex will only affect threads within the same process.  When you call pthread_mutex_destroy, it will destroy the mutex for the threads in that process in which you call it.  If you want to use a mutex for processes you will need to use something other than a pthread mutex

Comment: But why???? It seems to work fine! Those mutexes which are copied or duplicated by fork seem to be effectively the same mutexes. It wont work with exec, vfork or within unrelated programs, but what is the probelm with fork?

Comment: Well, if you really want to do it that way, you will need to delete each mutex in each process because they are only copies.  It only looks like it is working because the threads are copies of themselves.  When dealing with threads and you deal with them incorrectly, it can look fine and then the next day it won't.  You have to take this into account when dealing with concurrent programming

Comment: You could also look at this through a different angle.  When passing a pointer to other methods, the other methods can change the value as they please.  However, if they send a copy, then the other method can modify the value all it wants, but it won't change the value that the caller has.  This is the same principle.  If you are copying the mutexes in each process that the fork makes, then you are making copies and the mutex is not managing all the threads in all the processes.  Each mutex only functions with the threads in the process in which it is copied to.

Comment: Will,I do not use any threads, I use only processes, but if I understand you correctly, you claim that the copied mutexes have an effect only in their own process, which makes them ofcourse useless. But then can you explain me what is PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED option good for. If it does not work with fork, what is it invented for? Do you really mean, that dispite specifying this option I additionally need to put the mutex into shared memory before forking? What is the point in this option then?

Comment: Originally I thought that after fork these are probably not only copied but also "duplicated" similar to what happens to file descriptors. So at the end they control the same system resource, because of which I thought they are effectively the same (system) mutexes.

Comment: as for the PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED flag, look here: http://fixunix.com/unix/238233-question-about-pthread_process_shared-attribute.html

Comment: a pthread is a thread, therefore, a pthread_mutex is a mutex that deals with threads.

Comment: Well my question is actually rather that does pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED) place the mutex into shm automatically or I need to separately mmap it. If it does not what is it good for???

Comment: Also the example here: http://books.google.hu/books?id=9L5RZ6-IpLEC&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED+with+forked+processes&source=bl&ots=x4u9eM3ax_&sig=eQrQLtlPJLYS8VMCOLrIBzKOsvo&hl=hu&sa=X&ei=tNx_UJuFL4uSswbq34DYCg&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBzgU#v=onepage&q=PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED%20with%20forked%20processes&f=false uses no mmap (on page 202). Is it an incorrect example then? This seems to be a book.

Comment: Note the forum you pointed to does not talk about fork. On linux fork is copy-on-write, so it is not even evident that these are different copies, since I do not change them after fork. Finaly why cant fork point the two variables to the same system resource (if this makes sense), like file descriptors referencing the same file after fork.

Comment: If you will look further into my link, I wanted you to look at this particular quote:  "They (being the pthread mutexes with the PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED flag)  also have the concept of an
owner, which can be both good and bad, as it introduces problems if the owner dies while holding the mutex."  It is discussing how the mutex is used among several processes and that situation is usually created by using a fork.  You can have two different processes or threads with variables that are the same, it is just not good parallel programming practice to have many global variables like this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18247/discussion-between-will-and-user1132655)